# Save as you go pattern in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am after your expert opinion for achieving the following task using C#, Asp.Net SQL 2008/2012.

Say I have a form that has the following textbox's and it maps to a table in DataBase.

- ID : Identity
- Title
- Name
- Surname
- DOB

Say I hit new contact and am presented with the form.

If I enter my "Name" and hit tab I want to create a record straight away. Then if I enter "Surname" that will be an update and so on. So I want to update/commit on the fly

I want this kind of functionality for all my forms.

What would be the starting point to look at to achieve this.

Should I be using services for CRUDS or what short of model should I be looking at?

Update :
Below are images for better understanding.

If you have a Gmail/Google account try creating a new contact as and you will understand what I am after.

In short I want to implement this sort of functionality.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know why there is 3 downvote there. Those who downvote better leave comment or reasons, for better learning

Comment: For the question itself, I think there are too much non-technical terms here. Like 'Say I hit...', when it will be? What to be hit? A button? Then for 'If I enter my "Name" and hit tab ...' is it only happen when pressing tab? Or do you mean in more general way of 'when I lost my focus in the textbox'? And moreover, it will be better if you show the UI mock design so we can understand better.

Comment: Upvoted because the question is concise, provides an example, and is clearly asking for a starting point rather than a whole solution.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that I think this is a `bad idea` and the fact that you will have multiple requests per form per user, and the fact that if a user will go back to edit a field that they misspelled, you will have additional requests, so it's a lot of waste ... Aside from my opinion on this, here's where you can start:

1. Consider that you want this to happen from user interaction on the client (I.e., user's web browser), you need to make an AJAX call every time a user moves from one textbox to another.
2. Since you will want to use AJAX, you should look at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) which has some nice Ajax methods for you to use.
3. A user can move from a textbox by pressing tab, or clicking the mouse, so you will want to handle both of those events. The keyword here is `focus` and there are events which are fired that correspond to this. With jQuery, you can use the `.Blur()` method.
4. Now, since you probably don't want to rewrite the same code over and over again on each textbox, you might want to consider creating a `custom class` that derives from `TextBox`, say AutoUpdateTextBox or something similar, that has the needed jQuery associated with it built in. Don't just have it print a bunch of JavaScript, as you only need a JavaScript function once and you can pass parameters to it, such as the TextBoxID and Value.
5. Finally, you need some handler that accepts this AJAX call and updates your database. There are fifty million ways to create one. If you are using ASP.net Web Forms, you can create an ASHX handler and add the appropriate database saving logic (or data layer access logic, more appropriately) to that handler. A handler is not a page, it acts as a URL that just takes some parameters and returns any result. It does not execute the asp.net LifeCycle.

   Alternately, if using ASP.net MVC, you can set up a route and have a controller handle this and again, return just a true/false value as the whole response stream, or maybe JSON as was suggested in Ankur Singhal's answer. It might be easier with web forms.

   You can even create a web service or WCF service, but all you really need is a basic handler.

Well I hope this is enough to get you started, without giving you an entire solution. The components I have outlined, if you start to look at them one by one, as a complete set, will accomplish what you want to do.

If I may suggest, it may be wiser and more performant to think of a way to do this without updating EVERY time a user goes to a new textbox. You can keep a JavaScript object on your page which after a certain event (let's say user clicks "next" button on the page, or you provide a "save for later" button) then fires off an AJAX request with the values of the entire form to your handler or Web Service.

The key here in my outline above, and I hope it makes sense, is that when you have a requirement like the one you mentioned, you want to break it down into its various components. As you do more programming, that "how to break down my project or idea into smaller parts" will become easier.

Once you have the parts sort of outlined, you can start to build each part, and then when you get stuck, and ask a specific question about something you're stuck with, people here on SO will gladly help.

As they say, "How do you eat an elephant? - one bite at a time!" (I don't know anyone who has actually put that to the test with an elephant, but you get the point...)

Good luck!

Comment: That's really helpful. and thank you for going through the pain of writing it up.

Comment: That's really helpful and thank you for going through the pain of writing up. I am aware that its lot of waste when doing so many request's but then that's what I am asked to do. I will take your advise on breaking up the project but at the same time I am trying to find what would be a best set of technologies that I could utilize.

Comment: @vishalvatsal - no worries. You have all the technologies you need at your disposal with ASP.net and jQuery, honestly. This is a pretty specific requirement that you are not likely to find an "out of the box" implementation for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Services and consume them using Javascript. Also use JSON between the two.